# Is it possible to access the bluetooth in android [enable() or disable()] without the user interaction?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am developing an Android application which will access the Bluetooth to enable and disable it without any user interaction. Can somebody help me on how to do it?

Answer (score 9):

You can do this by using BluetoothAdapter:

```
    BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().disable();
    BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().enable();
```

And add ths permission to manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

Comment: Now this also prompt to permission dialog to ON BT.

Comment: This works on Nougat - I just tested it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIU, you need [BluetoothAdapter.enable()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#enable%28%29) & [BluetoothAdapter.disable()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#disable%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

To enable/disable Bluetooth programmatically without user interaction, use the following code:

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();    
if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) { //Disable it if enabled
    Intent localIntent;
    localIntent = new Intent();
    localIntent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
    localIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE");
    localIntent.setData(Uri.parse("4"));
    getBroadcast(paramContext, 0, localIntent, 0).send();
} else { //Enable if disabled
    Intent localIntent;
    localIntent = new Intent();
    localIntent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
    localIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE");
    localIntent.setData(Uri.parse("4"));
    getBroadcast(paramContext, 0, localIntent, 0).send();
}
```

And in your *Manifest.xml* file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

yes it is.

```
private static BluetoothAdapter getBA(){
    return BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
}

/*Methode startet das Bluetooth Modul
 */
public static void BT_ON(){
    BA = getBA();
    BA.enable();
}

public static void BT_STATUS(){
    BA = getBA();
}
```

Comment: It still worked for me on my Android Marshmallow. I am however targeting API 22 to avoid permission dialogs, which worked fine except for that it was still asking to Allow or Deny for the Bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue recently. The target android SDK version is 28.

Based on Android doc the `enable()`

> This method was deprecated in API level 33. Starting with
> Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU, applications are not allowed to
> enable/disable Bluetooth. Compatibility Note: For applications
> targeting Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU or above, this API will always
> fail and return false. If apps are targeting an older SDK
> (Build.VERSION_CODES.S or below), they can continue to use this API.
>
> Deprecation Exemptions:
>
> Device Owner (DO), Profile Owner (PO) and system apps.

Hence, to use `enable()/disable()` without worring SDK version, the app needs to have system permission

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...
    android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"
    ...>
```

and otehr bluetooth permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

One thing I found annoy after the adapter is enabled is based on the [article](https://proandroiddev.com/to-find-a-beacon-without-losing-it-my-journey-into-a-realm-of-bluetooth-low-energy-on-android-aa3e2c2923aa), the ble scanner could be `null` if the `BluetoothAdapter` is disabled. In my case, after the `enable()` is called the `BluetoothApater` is not enabled immediatele by some reason that I can not figure out. So when I do `var bleScanner = bluetoothAdapter.bluetoothLeScanner` the `bleScanner` is `null`. The solution I have is not ideal, but works

```
suspend fun scanDevices() {
...
    bluetoothAdapter.enable()
    var bleScanner = bluetoothAdapter.bluetoothLeScanner
    run waitBleAdapterAvailable@{
        repeat(20) {
            if (null == bleScanner) {
                delay(100)
                bleScanner = bluetoothAdapter.bluetoothLeScanner
            } else {
                return@waitBleAdapterAvailable
            }
        }
    }
    bleScanner.?{
        bleScanner.startScan(filters, settings, scanCallback)
        ...
        bleScanner.stopScan
    }
...
}
```